# crash when using FILE descriptor with popen across unix file system

Tags: c++, unix, filesystems, popen

We have a piece of legacy code that uses Flex with C-style FILE* descriptors. To support reading compressed files into Flex, we extended the "open" semantics to open gzip'ed files using

```
FILE* file = popen("gzip -cd <filename>");
```

rather than `fopen`.

We've encountered some problems recently where attempting this across a unix filesystem (probably another filesystem mounted using NFS on a NetApp) causes this entire code stream to crash (segfault), the first message we see is

> gzip: stdout: Broken Pipe

and our own crash frame. 
If we take the file and move it to the local filesystem where the process is running, there is no segfault and everything works as normal.

What have we tried to replicate or fix?

- read files compressed using gzip/ bzip2 etc from internal test NFS filesystems
- verify that the target file can be opened
- "open" the file and read a few bytes to make sure it can be opened by this process

All of this succeeds and yet we still encounter the crash.

We are out of ideas and could use some suggestions.

Sam Appleton

Comment: Have you considered using `zlib`?

Comment: Does the segfault occur during popen or during a later command? Have you tried running the code through valgrind? It can often tell you what the segfault was.

Comment: Also, post the entire stack trace from a segfault.  It could provide clues as to the root cause.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate your problem. In addition to the suggestions about the stack trace, you may consider providing a listing for a minimal program that produces the error.

Comment: We'll try using "zlib" directly - by opening the file descriptor and then passing to zlib. The latency is quite long because we have to try at a customer site, since obviously we can't replicate internally.

Comment: We do extensive valgrind --leak_check=full regressions and this has never come up

Comment: Barmar - thanks so much. I tried switching directly to a istream-derived class that uses zlib/bzlib directly (rather than POPEN) and it appears these problems are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you test it, SIGPIPE has its default action (kill the gzip process). When the process runs on your client's side, SIGPIPE is masked. Here's a minimal program that reproduces the error:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SZ 4096

void mask()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (-1 == sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0))
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char buf[SZ];

#ifdef MASK
    mask();
#endif

    FILE * f = popen("gzip -dc foo.gz", "r");
    if (0 != fread(buf, SZ, 1, f))
    {
        fwrite(buf, SZ, 1, stdout);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", pclose(f));
}
```

And here's the output with and without MASK:

```
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ gcc -DMASK -o foomask foo.c
$ /foo > /dev/null
13
$ /foomask > /dev/null 

gzip: stdout: Broken pipe
256
$
```

In short, it has nothing to do with NFS. That's a red herring.